# What is wrong with my code of deleting duplicates from a list?

Tags: python, list, duplicates, python-3.10

```
number = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1]
 
number.reverse()
        for element in number:
            if number.count(element) > 1:
                number.remove(element)

 number.reverse()

# when I execute this program for this particular list the duplicates are not removed why?
```

Comment: Don't remove items from a list while you're iterating over the list.  Confusing things happen, just like this.

Comment: removing items from a list while iterating over it would make iterations shorter and may not go through entire list.

Answer (score 2):

use set

```
number = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1]
print(set(number))
```

output is `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`